# How to decipher ngrx API

Tags: ngrx

Can someone help me to go through this definition step by step?
`select<T, Props, K>(pathOrMapFn: string | ((state: T, props?: Props) => any), propsOrPath: string | Props, ...paths: string[])`
I don't get the hang of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the definition of the a `selector`.

- `T`: the incoming state
- `Props`: if you're calling a selector [with props](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/parameterized-selectors)
- `K`: the result of the `selector`
- `pathOrMapFn` can either be the path to the state or a [createSelector](https://ngrx.io/api/store/createSelector)
- `propsOrPath` can either be the path to the state or the `props`
- `...paths: string[]` the rest of the path

With path to state I mean: `select('featureState', 'persons', 'entities')`

Comment: Thank you! Where is T defined as incoming state and where is K defined as result of the selector? From where can I get this information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate a bit more?
Maybe  a a couple of links that might help:
- the source code https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts#L22
- TypeScript generics https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html